# How to get the PR number in the travis.yml script

Tags: travis-ci

I know about the `${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}` which is a boolean env variable denoting if we are currently building the pull request or not, but is it possible to obtain the PR number? What's the value of `${TRAVIS_BRANCH}` if the `${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}` is true?

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer:

`${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}` contains either `"false"` if it's not the build of a pull request or the pr number

source: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables